# how to identify slow subscribers in ctp?

Tags: kdb

I have a CTP to which I have about 12-13 procs subscribing to the same table.

There were no issues with it until recently when the data flow tripled for said table around 1 - 3 pm.

```
//counts by hour

©¬ time x
2021.10.20D10:00:00.000000000   2.861138
2021.10.20D11:00:00.000000000   6.550263
2021.10.20D12:00:00.000000000   12.427463
2021.10.20D13:00:00.000000000   15.083131
2021.10.20D14:00:00.000000000   10.690055
2021.10.20D15:00:00.000000000   4.285406
```

there is no fancy logic in the ctp. I can see the tp struggling to publish to it.

when I do a `count each .z.W` in the ctp ... not messages stuck in the handles.

How can I find my slow subscriber?

At the moment I have to kill the ctp and restart all connections.

**UPDATE1**: my issue is that ctp is a slow subscriber, but there are no messages stuck in the handles in the ctp. should I assume the slow processing is due to the upd function ?

the upd function is :

```
(Roundtrip: 00:09.844)
{[t;x] t insert x;.u.jcounts[t]+:count x;}
```

which is a very basic definition and should not cause these issues.

Comment: are you using `-25!` in the ctp for publishing?

Comment: no . I am using the generic .u.pub function

Comment: I think the CTP may be the slow subscriber. Are all your subscribers getting the same data or is there atleast some overlap? -25! Or async broadcast will serialize the data once for publishing to subscribers who want the same thing. Kdb >= 3.4 supports it

Comment: is the chained tp in batch mode? can you share `system"t"` and your `.u.pub`

Answer (score 0):

Besides the natural answer of adding fancy client logging into your tickerplants (Simon Garland wrote the original templates: https://code.kx.com/q/kb/using-dotz/#tracking-clients-and-servers), I find netstat to be useful:

```
netstat -altnp | grep -e Proto -e 1234
```

Run that on the machine that hosts your CTP and replace 1234 with the port of your CTP. This gives info on who's connected to your CTP and also gives details of receive-queue and send-queue. It gives the PID of the programme/application that is connected. It won't give you the answer on a plate but should help you to know where to look.

Comment: Hey. thank you very much for your reply. 

I know which processes connect to it, I just don't know how to see which one is causing the issues. the tp which publishes to ctp is having issues publishing but there are no messages stuck in the handles (.z.W) in the ctp as if ... there are no slow subscribers. So .. atm I assume the issue is in the ... upd function in the ctp ? but the upd is very basic 
--->>>
(Roundtrip: 00:09.844)
{[t;x] t insert x;.u.jcounts[t]+:count x;}

Comment: Could somebody be sending queries/commands to your CTP? Other than .u.sub and replay-related requests

Comment: mm. I don't expect anyone to send queries to these ctp. it's an internal ctp. my problem is whcih of the 12 processes connecting to it is causing the issues. I don't really know how to debug going forward.